# Remote Hook on loopback-component-storage

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I was trying to use loopback-component-storage. It's all working fine.

The one thing that I cannot figure out is how do I observe a file upload completion within loopback, when the following API is called:

http://localhost:3000/api/Epubs/{container}/upload | POST

I tried using afterRemote("*.*") & observe("access"). None of them seem to trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use afterRemote on method 'upload'. In your case that will be

```
Epub.afterRemote( 'upload', function( ctx, modelInstance, next) { 
 ...
 next();
});
```

See [remote hooks docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks)

Comment: I was making the mistake of typing Epub.afterRemote("upload", function(ctx, next) {...})

Comment: Epub must be "Container". So it is something like this: Container,afterRemote(.......